# Violating a country's law outside that country

Tags: intellectual-property

Assuming that a reporter from country B called Bob has somehow got a video from country A. He then puts in on a news page that is open to the whole world. Later, A citizen called Cob from Country C watches the video. There is a warning sign and a message in the video but it is written in Country A's language and Cob  doesn't understand. What consequences would Bob and Cob have? (Bob and Cob don't know each other, it is unknown if Bob understands or has read the warning. But it is known that countries B and C might have similar laws related to the warning)

Comment: Is this something that is illegal to view in "Cob"'s country? What is the warning supposed to say? Are you asking about copyright, or about content?

Comment: It is illegal to view in Cob’s and Bob’s country, but the three countries all have different consequences for violating this law. The warning is not about copyright, it’s about things that are banned in a country

Comment: This is much too vague to answer.

Comment: Agree, too vague. "Bob is a reporter" is a relevant concern in some but not all real-world jurisdictions. Since we don't know that, all further information in the question becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Voting to close as the situation is too vague.  Is this video a pirated movie or a video with state secrets on it (drastically changes the outcome).

Answer (score 3):

Any country is free to decide what actions are considered to be  crimes, and what crimes are prosecuted depending on whether you perform the action in the country, outside the country, and depending on whether you are a citizen, a resident, both, or neither. They can also decide what are accepted defences in court and which are not.

Any other country is free to decide under which circumstances they will ever extradite someone to that first country.

Now you have to check the laws of the individual countries.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question involves "intellectual property", video, and warning messages, I assume this relates to something like the FBI copyright violation notice that appears on numerous video works. If a Somali person in Somalia who knows no English sees but does not understand the warning, are they then immune to the legal consequences of copyright infringement because they have not been put on notice that copying is illegal? They are not: no legal system has the principle "ignorance of the law is a valid excuse". Every person is expected to know all of the laws (not to suggest that that is actually possible). If you enter Cambodia with a supply of drugs and do not understand the warning sign in Khmer that tells you that you are breaking the law, you cannot use that ignorance of Cambodian law to escape punishment. However: you have to be in Cambodia for Cambodia to be able to enforce its law. So if you are in country C and view a video that is illegal in country A, country A cannot enforce its law against you, until you go to country A.

Comment: Country A can enforce its laws if you ever touch the ground of country A, or if country C extradites you, or if country A kidnaps you.